# Modify label printer definition .prn file

Tags: c#, xml

i am trying to write a program in c#.net

to modify a thermal label printer .prn file having

```
   <xpml></page></xpml><xpml><page quantity='25' pitch='35.0 mm'></xpml>N
```

how can i change quantity attribute at run time by using c#.net from 25 to user input say 50 or 100 or 5? so it will be

```
<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><page quantity='50' pitch='35.0 mm'></xpml>N
```

or

```
<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><page quantity='100' pitch='35.0 mm'></xpml>Nenter code here
```

or

```
<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><page quantity='5' pitch='35.0 mm'></xpml>N
```

Complete .prn file

```
<xpml><page quantity='0' pitch='35.0 mm'></xpml>I8,A
q843
O
JF
ZT
Q280,25
<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><page quantity='2' pitch='35.0 mm'></xpml>N
b569,70,Q,m2,s5,eL,"12345678"
A686,52,2,4,1,1,N,"12345678"
A823,267,2,4,1,1,N,"Hardware Kit (Egypt)"
b149,70,Q,m2,s5,eL,"12345678"
A266,52,2,4,1,1,N,"12345678"
A403,267,2,4,1,1,N,"Hardware Kit (Egypt)"
P2
<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><end/></xpml>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            string xml = "<root><xpml><page/></xpml><xpml><page quantity='25' pitch='35.0 mm'/></xpml></root>";

            XElement element = XElement.Parse(xml);
            XElement page = element.Descendants("page").Where(x => x.Attribute("quantity") != null).FirstOrDefault();
            page.SetAttributeValue("quantity", 50);
```

Comment: the line structure can not be modified as shown in example, if i try to run using sample by removing last character N i am getting error 'The 'xpml' start tag on line 1 position 2 does not match the end tag of 'page'. Line 1, position 9.'

Comment: What you posted is not valid xml.  I assumed you edited the original xml to only post a small section of the xml and did the edits wrong.

Comment: yes, i have made many changes to actual post to better communicate, i m sorry if this has caused any bad feeling to you

Comment: This is more complicated than you think.  It look like for each quantity there are three rows (one starting with 'b' and two starting with 'A') and there is a final row that has P2 (probably the quantity number).  Then you have two pages and how do you know which page gets changed?  It looks like the first page is 'I8,A' and seconds page 'N".  Do you have a description of what the lines actually means?  What you have is still not valid xml since the text items and not inside a TAG.

Comment: Did you post the file exactly as you got it from PC?   If so you can modify the file , but not using XML parsing.  You would have to parse as a string.

Comment: Lines beginning with A,b,LO are epl printer commands respectively for text,barcode,line respectively. And the parameters are the begin and end of objects printing co-ordinates and few more things, but last parameter in these lines embedded in double quote is values .

Answer (score 0):

following string manipulation /Regex could solve my problem
but now i discovered that there is no need to modify this line only
the P command actually controls the no of required print

```
string pattern = @"(quantity=')([0-9]+)";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
string changedvlu = regex.Replace(rowsInTextFile[6], "quantity='" + 
dgvrLabels.Cells["labels2print"].Value.ToString());
string cmdlableqty = rowsInTextFile[6].ToString();
int findpicthpos = cmdlableqty.IndexOf("pitch");
if (findpicthpos>0)
{
   rowsInTextFile[6] = "<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><page quantity ="
            + "\'" + dgvrLabels.Cells["labels2print"].Value + "\' ";
   rowsInTextFile[6] += cmdlableqty.Substring(findpicthpos);
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Problem in setting label qty:call developer");
```